# Ribbon / flag on sides shape with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have Been trying to do some sort of ribbon flag style in CSS, but I haven't been able to do it, I wonder if anyone can point me right and also if knows any good tutorial to how work with these types of shapes

This is what i want to achieve

[image]

Comment: I have closed it as a dupe (even though the linked question is about border shape) because those approaches still hold good for this one and you would just need to add `background-color` or `fill` depending on whether you choose CSS or SVG.

Comment: @Harry sometimes you need the proper keywords to find something,

Comment: Yes @DannyG and that's why duplicate questions are not bad questions. They serve as good signposts.

Comment: Indeed, and that question has a really good answer. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  background-color: #AC4244;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 5px 20px 0;
  border-color: transparent #ffffff transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```